# how to find files of current date in remote server and copy those file to local server using rcp using shell scripting (ksh)?

Tags: shell-script, find

I have two servers: 1.EOS(Linux RHEL 4) and 2.domain1(Solaris 10)

In EOS, ftp rcp scp is blocked.

In EOS, I have some backup files of oracle database saved in `/user/orac/monthly/` path. My backup end at 9pm. Three backup file are generated per day. I want to copy these three files to my domain1 server.
Manually I copied from EOS to domain1 like the following command:

```
rcp -p EOS:/user/orac/monthly/daily_backup_ORAC_edshhyjjak_3445_1 .
```

But it is easier for one specific file. But how to find the current dated files and copy them (three files) to my local server?

Files are like this,

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle dba 9835748338 Mar 18 20:40  daily_backup_ORAC_e6rvgtgt_3445_1
-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle dba   54546677 Mar 18 20:40  daily_backup_ORAC_e7rvfght_3446_1
-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle dba 5454555666 Mar 18 20:40  daily_backup_ORAC_e8rvfdhj_3447_1
```

These three files of today's date to be copied to `domain1:/database/backup_eos/` path

Alos tried

`find /user/orac/monthly/ -name daily_backup_ORAC_*' -mtime -exec rcp -p "{}" domain1:/database/backup_eos/ \;`

But it is giving error as rcp is blocked in EOS!
I have to run this command in domain1 which will find current date files in EOS of this `/user/orac/monthly/` path and copy in domain1 `/database/backup_eos/` path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in EOS at the end of backup run

```
find /user/orac/monthly/ -name 'daily_backup_ORAC_*' -mtime -1 -print > /var/tmp/todays_backup.txt
```

in domain1 do

```
rcp EOS:/var/tmp/todays_backup.txt /var/tmp
for f in $(< /var/tmp/todays_backup.txt)
do
    rcp -p EOS:$f /database/backup_eos/
done
```

this way, find is done locally, and domain2 only has to fetch list and get file.

if `$(< )` is not supported use

```
 while read f
 do
    /var/tmp/todays_backup.txt
 done < /var/tmp/todays_backup.txt
```

Comment: Yes it is working :-)